# Is every function that is continuous and bounded on a certain interval, is integrable in that interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Maybe its a stupid question, sorry.

The question i ask my self is if every integral of a function, where the function is bounded and continuous on the interval of the integral than i can conclude that the function is integrable in that interval?

- The question is asked from the point of view of improper integrals.

Divide it to two:

1. Intervals of the form $[a,b)$
2. Intevals of the form $[a,\infty)$ - This is the part where i think i have a problem, see below.

*For intevals of the form $[a,b]$ its by definition integrable at that interval -  for continuous functions

---

What i think:

For the first case: $[a,b)$ we can expand the interval to $[a,b]$, in that interval the function is continuous and bounded except, maybe, to finite number of points, therefore we can conclude its integrable.

For the second case and more problematic, $[a,\infty)$ namely: $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$  can i prove it or is it even a false claim?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried $f \equiv 1$?

Comment: Thank you, of course, its bounded and continuous but the integral is surly diverges... i knew its a stupid question... Thank you. If the managers see, they can even close the question.

Yet, if i can ask something please, are there conditions on a function that i can say, on the infinite interval, by function properties, that its integrable, not talking about the form, like $\frac{1}{x^2}$ which is integrable, but on the function properties, such as bonded, continuous etc...@PhoemueX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of intervals of the type $[a,b)$, you are right: extende $f$ to $[a,b]$ putting, say, $f(b)=0$. The this new function is bounded and it has a single point at which it is discontinuous, at most. So, yes, it will be integrable.

But for intervals of the type $[a,\infty)$ this doesn't work: the integral $\int_a^\infty1\,\mathrm dt$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Thank you, and as i asked in the comments, are there conditions on a function that i can say, on the *infinite* interval, by function properties, that its integrable, not talking about the form, like $\frac{1}{x^2}$ which is integrable, but on the function properties, such as bonded, continuous etc..

Comment: I am not aware of any interesting condition for that to happen.

Comment: Ok thats also good to know, thank you for the help.